# Variable Alphabetics Permutation Algorithm - Simple yet mind-boggling

Tags: algorithm

I recently came across an apparently simple problem but it turned out to be SO mind boggling that I couldn't sleep for 2 days.

Here is the problem:

a variable will consist of number of characters -> Say $i=5. You need to print every possible alphabetical combination from $i=2 to $i=5.

The output for $i=5 needs to be:
**aa
ab
ac
...
zz
aaa
aab
...
zzz
aaaa
aaab
....
zzzz
aaaaa
.....
zzzzz**

You need to use **ONLY for loops** or **foreach** or **while loops** to achieve this (no functions to be used) and PRINT the output for each string formed instead of saving in an array. *Please do not use a for loop inside of for loop inside of for loop because $i can be 100 or 200.*

You can take an array of alphabets from 'a' to 'z'. Can someone please help me out with a simple elegant solution to this?

Comment: I searched stackoverflow for the possible solutions but found out that people are very keen on using **recursive functions** As I mentioned, I  should NOT be using a function at all because I do not want to store these strings but rather just print them. 

I have tried using two flags with an array with number of rows = $i and just print the [0] element of all the arrays. But after the first row it all becomes too hard to process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the loop you have an array `aa`. In the loop look at the array.

If the array is the sequence of all `z` then replace the contents with a sequence of all `a` that has a length incremented by 1. If new array has length larger than maximum then exit the loop.

Otherwise look at the tail of the array, which is always in the form `Xz*`, where `X` is any letter except `z`, followed by zero or more letters `z`. Replace this tail of the array with `Ya*`, where `Y` is the letter that follows `X`, ie. Y = X + 1, and `a*` is the sequence of letters `a` of the exact same length as was the original sequence of letters `z` (remember that length can be zero).

In any case write the new contents of the array to output and repeat the loop.

You'll need just two loops. Outer is the main loop that prints a new value in each iteration. Inner is the loop that converts all `z`'s into `a`'s.

Comment: excellent solution! I got the output that I needed. For everyone who is looking for the solution -> Here it is https://gist.githubusercontent.com/trocker/ed43d3289d84de46f5dc/raw/9658db5e2e8fbb846dd51a6d151423513bb265d3/gistfile1.txt

Comment: @fineTuneFork I haven't given code because the question feels like a homework or some kind of learning exercise. You could give the code in your own additional answer. I'd just note that string incrementing operator in PHP is magical enough that it also turns `zz` into `aaa`. If this is homework I don't think the code will be accepted by the teacher.

Comment: If this was homework I'd have surely copied it instead of writing the code myself... hahaha... do you have any sources of interesting problems like these though? (I'm a software professional for a decade now)